# SSD SATA III on MB SATA I

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

Is it possible to run SSD drive with SATA3 on motherboard that uses only SATA?
Ex. Gigabyte GA-EP45-DS3R motherboard with SSD SanDisk Plus 480GB?
I know that it will work as fast as SATA I.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your SATA III drive will function on a SATA I port at SATA I speeds.

From [SanDisk's](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii) website:

> SATA III specifications provide backward compatibility to function on
>   SATA I and SATA II ports. However, the maximum speed of the drive will
>   be slower due to the lower speed limitations of the port.

Answer (score 1):

The GA-EP45-DS3R uses SATA2. But yes, the drive will work on SATA1. You will just have to make sure that the drive either has some sort of garbage collection algorithm, make sure the used AHCI firmware has trim support or manually launch garbage collection using the manufacturer's tool.